# passing (size_t)-1 to snprintf_s

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

A question about the C++ Stackwalker here: 
https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker

```
#define _TRUNCATE ((size_t)-1)

enum
{
    STACKWALK_MAX_NAMELEN = 1024
}; 

void StackWalker::OnSymInit(LPCSTR szSearchPath, DWORD symOptions, LPCSTR szUserName)
{
    CHAR   buffer[STACKWALK_MAX_NAMELEN];
    size_t maxLen = STACKWALK_MAX_NAMELEN;
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
    maxLen = _TRUNCATE;
#endif
    _snprintf_s(buffer, maxLen, "SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '%s', symOptions: %d, UserName: '%s'\n",
        szSearchPath, symOptions, szUserName);
}
```

maxlen is first set to 1024 and then if VC++ version >= 1400 (which it is) then it is set to (unsigned)-1, in other words at least UINT_MAX.

Then maxlen is passed to _snprintf_s, so it will cause a buffer overflow again if the string is larger than 1024 characters.

Am I missing something here? What could've been the reason to set maxlen at UINT_MAX? Using a safe string function but without safety?

Comment: Note, code does not use `(unsigned)-1`, but `(size_t)-1` which is `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: pretty sure size_t is always unsigned

Comment: If you want `UINT_MAX` use `UINT_MAX`! There's no guarantee that `(size_t)-1 == UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen I am sure that `size_t` is not always `unsigned`, in most cases it is `unsigned long`.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen `size_t` is some _unsigned_ type. It might be the same as `unsigned`, `unsigned long` or others.

Comment: the question was more about why set the maxlen to _TRUNCATE when buffer's size is only 1024

Comment: True, `SIZE_MAX./UINT_MAX` is a side issue, yet you could amend the post to not include the distraction and improve clarity.

Comment: size_t is required by C and C++ to be an unsigned type, but it could be unsigned short, unsigned long, unsigned long long, or (I think) something entirely different.

Comment: Since this code is all MS-specific, the theoretical possibilities for the type to which `size_t` could be aliased are really only of theoretical interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That  overload for `_snprintf_s` (a Visual Studio specific function) can only be used in C++ if the buffer length can be deduced from the first argument.

See the second paragraph under `Remarks` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-s-snprintf-s-l-snwprintf-s-snwprintf-s-l?view=vs-2017) for a description of the `_TRUNCATE` magic value and what it does.

But note that for earlier versions of VS, the code implements this function using `_snprintf`, which knows nothing about the macro `_TRUNCATE`:

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1400
// ...
#define _snprintf_s _snprintf
```

In order to be able to use `_snprintf`, he has to arrange for the buffer length to be passed through. `snprintf` does not have a templated overload which can deduce the length of character buffer arguments. Also, he needs to `#define _TRUNCATE` because in those same old versions, it doesn't exist in `stdlib.h`.

All in all, this strikes me as a very clunky workaround for an unnecessarily complicated non-standard library function.

Comment: I see, _snprintf is actually a template function which knows the size of the buffer passed in already! And _TRUNCATE means something like "dontcare", you know the size already. Weird C/C++ mix, clunky indeed. Thanks for pointing it out!